# How can I center cols in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center, col

I have 3 cols:

[image]

I want to center the cols in the middle of page for responsive design. So if I view them on my mobile phone they should among themselves. So how can center them?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-flash"><h3>Professional</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-picture"><h3>Exactly</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"><h3>Custom</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid layout centers itself automatically. I modified your code just a bit:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-flash">      
        <h3>Professional</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
        <h3>Exactly</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot">
        <h3>Custom</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/deC37/474/).
Remember that columns always have to sum to 12 (4+4+4) inside a row.

Comment: So was it the extra `div` that was making the text not centered?

Comment: Yep, the extra `col-xs-4` "pushed" all the rest to the left. There is nothing else to do here.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add your own class to the row `div` (e.g. `col-center`) and then center the row using CSS:

```
.col-center {
  margin: auto;
}
```